# How can I modify val members during construction in Kotlin

Tags: constructor, kotlin, final

In Java I'm able to modify `final` members in the constructor. Please see the following example

```
class Scratch {

  private final String strMember;

  public Scratch(String strParam) {
    this.strMember = strParam.trim();
  }        
}
```

Is there a way in Kotlin to modify `val` members during construction, in this case to `trim()` them before the parameter value are assigned to the field.

If not, what is the recommended workaround to do so without generating too much overhead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can declare an argument to the constructor that isn't marked with `val` or `var`. This has the effect of being local to the constructor and lost once class construction is complete. Take that argument and set it to whatever you want.

```
class Scratch(str: String) {
    private val strMember = str.trim()
}
```

Comment: Ah, seems pretty concise. Wouldn't work with `data` classes, though?

Comment: I don't think that's a good use of Data Classes, TBH. Here's a good answer (to a slightly different question, but essentially the same) covering why, and how to get around it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46376746/49746

Comment: And neither do I the more I'm dealing with it. Data classes tend to support anemic domain model rather than rich domain objects with multiple inheritances.

Answer (score 2):

Like this: constructor parameters are available during initialization of properties.

```
class Scratch(strParam:String) {
    private val strMember = strParam.trim()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your `strParam final property` as follow

```
class Scratch(strParam : String) {
    val strParam : String = strParam 
        get() = field.trim()
}
```

So, you can use them inside and outside your `Scratch class`

Comment: This doesn't seem efficient since every get() call will execute `trim` and allocate new `String` instance.