# Overriding get method for variable in class kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-class

I have a model class in Java which I converted to data class in kotlin

```
public class VideoAssets implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
String type;

@SerializedName("mpeg")
@Expose
List<Mpeg> mpeg = null;

@SerializedName("hls")
@Expose
String hls;

@SerializedName("widevine")
@Expose
WideVine wideVine;

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public List<Mpeg> getMpeg() {
    return mpeg;
}

public void setMpeg(List<Mpeg> mpeg) {
    this.mpeg = mpeg;
}

public String getHls() {
    hls = Macros.INSTANCE.replaceURl(hls);
    return hls;
}

public void setHls(String hls) {
    this.hls = hls;
}

public WideVine getWideVine() {
    return wideVine;
}

public void setWideVine(WideVine wideVine) {
    this.wideVine = wideVine;
}
}
```

As you see I want to change the value of variable `hls` when I retrieve it.

I created the data class as below

```
data class VideoAssets(@SerializedName("mpeg") @Expose
                   var mpeg: List<Mpeg> = emptyList(),
                   @SerializedName("hls")
                   @Expose
                   var hls: String,
                   @SerializedName("widevine")
                   @Expose
                   val wideVine: WideVine? = null) : Serializable
```

I am struggling here as how should I update the get method for data class.
After searching and taking reference from [Override getter for Kotlin data class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492103/override-getter-for-kotlin-data-class)
I even created a non data class which doesn't seem to work

```
class VideoAssets(@SerializedName("mpeg") @Expose
              var mpeg: List<Mpeg> = emptyList(),
              @SerializedName("hls")
              @Expose
              val hlsUrl: String? = null,
              @SerializedName("widevine")
              @Expose
              val wideVine: WideVine? = null) : Serializable {
val hls: String? = hlsUrl
    get() = field?.let { Macros.replaceURl(it) }

}
```

Whenerver I try to retrieve `videoAssets.getHls()` it returns null while it should return the new value. The object `videoAssets.gethlsUrl()` has the value but not `videoAssets.getHls()' is always null.

Can someone point me what I am missing?

Comment: I tried to recreate your issue, but [this code does not reproduce the issue that you describe](https://pl.kotl.in/jS8J5khtx).  Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code:

```
val hls: String? = hlsUrl
    get() = field?.let { Macros.replaceURl(it) }
```

So what this is doing, is creating a property called `hls` and giving it a backing field (a variable) called `field`. It initially sets that to whatever value for `hlsUrl` was passed into the constructor (might be null).

The getter code takes that value for `field`, and *if it isn't null* it calls that `replaceURl` function and returns the result, otherwise it returns null.

So if you set `hlsUrl` to null, `field` will always be null and the `hls` getter will always return null. Even if you update `hlsUrl` later (whicb I'm assuming you're doing, the code runs fine for me if I pass in a value to the constructor) the value of `field` is fixed at initialisation.

Also your Java code runs differently - when that gets the new value of `hls`, it stores that and uses it in the function call of the next `get`. You're never changing the value of `field` so your Kotlin code uses the initial value every time.

Technically you don't need the backing field since you're always effectively calling `hlsUrl?.let { Macros.replaceURl(it) }`. In that case you could make `hlsUrl` var and update that, or you can add a setter to your `hls` property and set the backing field when you `get` the new value

[Here's the Kotlin page on properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html), in case you haven't seen it!