# How to modify the parameter pass to kotlin data class?

Tags: kotlin, constructor, data-class

Say I have a data class

```
data class MyClass(val crop: Rect, val name: String)
```

But I want to make a copy of the Rect passed in since I don't want the value to be modified later. I don't want to the caller to call

```
MyClass(Rect(inCrop), "name")
```

in the code. How can I do this in my data class?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to elaborate on the definitions a bit. Not reproducible at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround I can think of is:

```
data class MyClass(private var privateCrop: Rect, val name: String) {
    val crop get() = privateCrop

    init {
        privateCrop = Rect(privateCrop)
    }
}
```

You make `crop` private and make it a var (`privateCrop`), then you add a public getter for it. Now you can copy it in an `init` block.

But I gotta admit, this is rather ugly. The better solution here I think is to change *`Rect`* to be immutable, but if `Rect` isn't in your control, then I guess it can't be helped. You might also consider using a regular class.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want to alter data class's like this. As per another solution's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46376746/4580610), you may find other peculiarities with this solution. The solution given by @Sweeper, also does not include providing a defensive copy, which you may want to do to avoid access to modifying the internal property field.

To quote:

> After spending almost a full year of writing Kotlin daily I've found that attempting to override data classes like this is a bad practice. There are 3 valid approaches to this, and after I present them, I'll explain why the approach other answers have suggested is bad.
>
> 1. Have your business logic that creates the data class alter the value to be 0 or greater before calling the constructor with the bad value. This is probably the best approach for most cases.
> 2. Don't use a data class. Use a regular class and have your IDE generate the equals and hashCode methods for you (or don't, if you don't need them). Yes, you'll have to re-generate it if any of the properties are changed on the object, but you are left with total control of the object.
>
> ```kotlin
>    class Test(value: Int) {
>      val value: Int = value
>        get() = if (field < 0) 0 else field
>
> override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
>        if (this === other) return true
>        if (other !is Test) return false
>        return true
>      }
>
>      override fun hashCode(): Int {
>        return javaClass.hashCode()
>      }
>    }
> ```
>
> 3. Create an additional safe property on the object that does what you want instead of having a private value that's effectively overriden.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31647844)